# A point is in $\partial A$ iff every neighborhood of it contains both a point of $A$ and a point of $X\setminus A$.

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

How to prove

> (c) A point is in $\partial A$ iff every neighborhood of it contains both a point of $A$ and a point of $X\setminus A$.
>   (d) A point is in $\operatorname{cl}(A)$ if and only if every neighborhood of it contains a point of $A$.

I have proved the partial results

> (a) A point is in $\operatorname{Int}A$ if and only if it has a neighborhood contained in $A$.
>   (b) A point is in $\operatorname{Ext}A$ if and only if it has a neighborhood contained in $X\setminus A$.

This gives the $\impliedby$ direction of (c), how to prove the other direction and (d)?

Source: Lee topological manifolds

Comment: What definition of $\partial A$ are you using?

Comment: x\ (int A union ext A)

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773) and 
[here](/help/notation).

Comment: Are neighborhoods necessarily open in your definition?  Also, do you mean $\partial A=\operatorname{cl}A\setminus(\operatorname{Ext}A\cup\operatorname{Int} A)$?  Sorry about all the questions, but differents texts define these concepts differently.

Comment: A neighbourhood of x is defined as an open set containing x. I mean $\partial A=X\setminus(\operatorname{Ext}A\cup\operatorname{Int} A)$

Comment: @TimRaczkowski Exterior and Closure are necessarily disjoint? $\mathrm{Ext} A = (X\setminus A)^\circ$ AFAIK...

Comment: Oh. I see now. I misunderstood.

Answer (score 0):

For (c), what if there exists a neighborhood $\mathcal{U}$ of one point $x$ that do not satisfy this condition, suppose that it does not intersect $\text{int}(A)$, then $\mathcal{U}$ would be in the $\text{ext}(A)$, meaning that $x$ is in the $\text{ext}(A)$

For (d), if you use the definition $\text{cl}(A):= A \cup \partial A,$ then you should use (c) and (a) to conclude

Answer (score 0):

**Hints**

$\implies$ for (c):
If you use the contrapositive of (a) and (b) you get that every neighborhood of a point in $\partial A$ is neither contained in $\mathrm{Int} A$ nor in $\mathrm{Ext} A$.
From this try to prove that any neighborhood must intersect both.

(d):
I guess you defined $\mathrm{cl} A := \mathrm{Int} A \cup \partial A$?
Then the $\implies$ case for a point in $\partial A$ is already settled by (c).
The $\implies$ case for a point in $A$ is trivial.
For the $\impliedby$ if every nbhd contains a point of $A$, either there exists a nbhd contiained in $A$ (thus the point is itself in $\mathrm{Int} A \subset \mathrm{cl} A$) or all contain also an exterior point, thus we are in $\partial A \subset \mathrm{cl} A$.