Proving that a point is in the boundary iff all neighbourhoods contain a point in $X \backslash A$ and $A$
This question has been asked before, however I am confused by some of the answers so I am asking again in the hope that someone can clarify what I am missing.
One of the proofs I have seen goes as follows.
Let $X$ be a topological space, and $A \subseteq X$, and also let ${\rm Int} A$, ${\rm Ext} A$, $\overline{A}$, and $\partial A$ denote the interior, exterior, closure, and boundary of $A$ respectively, where
$${\rm Int} A = \bigcup \left\{ C | C \subseteq A, C \text{ is open} \right\}$$
$$\overline{A} = \bigcap \left\{ C | A \subseteq C, C \text{ is closed} \right\}$$
$${\rm Ext} A = X \backslash \overline{A}$$
$$\partial A= X \backslash ({\rm Int} A \cup {\rm Ext} A)$$
Now consider $q \in \partial A$ and a neighborhood of $q$, $U \subseteq X$. Now assume $U \cap A = \emptyset$, then $U \cap {\rm Int} A = \emptyset$ so $U \subseteq {\rm Ext} A$.
then since $q \notin {\rm Ext} A$, contradiction.
The part I am stumped on is how it can be concluded that $U \subseteq {\rm Ext} A$; why couldn't $U$ contain some of the boundary points of $A$ and be a neighborhood for instance?

What is your definition of $\partial A$?


$X$ should be a space, not a set. 2. Please define $\operatorname{Int}$, $\operatorname{Ext}$, and $\partial$. 3. Please tell us where you have seen that proof.


@BenSteffan I've added my definition of the sets and fixed the 1st problem, as for the 3rd I found it on this thread as the first answer
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1329292/a-point-is-in-partial-a-iff-every-neighborhood-of-it-contains-both-a-point-of

All of the $/$'s should be $\setminus$'s.

@hff1, it is wrong indeed $\color{green}{\text{Ext}(A)=X,\text{\ }!\overline A}$ where $\overline A$ is the closure of $A$.

In the following, I use ${\rm Bd} A$ to denote the boundary of $A$ (same meaning as $\partial A$).
Well, suppose that $U$ intersects ${\rm Bd} A$, say at the point $x$. Then because ${\rm Bd} A \subseteq {\rm Cl} A$ (prove by basic set theory with your definitions), then $x \in {\rm Cl} A$. We thus have that $U$ is an open set that intersects ${\rm Cl} A$. This implies that $U$ intersects $A$, contrary to hypothesis.
The proof of the fact

If $U$ is an open set that intersects ${\rm Cl} A$, then $U$ intersects $A$.

from your definitions is straightforward. Suppose for the sake of contradiction that $U$ does not intersect $A$. Then ${\rm Cl} A - U = {\rm Cl} A \cap (X - U)$ is a strictly smaller set than ${\rm Cl} A$, is closed (being the intersection of closed sets), and contains $A$ (since $A \subseteq {\rm Cl} A$ and $A \subseteq X - U$). This obviously contradicts your definition of closure for ${\rm Cl} A$, as you can check.

Just checking to make sure I understand, is the contradiction here finding a smaller closed set than the closure of A? as the closure should be the smallest closed set containing A.

@DanLupu The main idea is that if you have a neighborhood that intersects the boundary of $A$, then it must necessarily intersect $A$ (which was disallowed by hypothesis). To prove that, we used the fact that ${\rm Cl} A$ is the smallest closed set containing $A$ to show that every open set that intersects ${\rm Cl} A$ also intersects $A$ - here, I proved that by contradiction.
